# Is there an HTML5 method for displaying a tiff image data already loaded into memory

Tags: javascript, html, memory, render, tiff

I have a tiff image stored in memory (in a javascript variable). What is the javascript or html technique for displaying this image in the browser window? Is there a "drawimage" type of function?

Comment: You could try setting the `<img>` src to `data:img/x-tiff;base64,` followed by the base64 encoded string

Comment: what type of variable is it in?

Comment: Hi, it is a string variable. I tried the following:  valueToDisplay = '<img alt="sample" src="data:image/x-tiff;base64,' + param.value + 'width="512" height="512" " >';  This didn't seem to work. I'm not much of a javascript or html programmer so not clear what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Native browser-support for tiff files is still pretty bad.
Wikipedia has a nice overview on browsers [Image format support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support).

That being said; since a .tiff image is still essentially a raster-image, one could indeed convert it (the tricky part is stuff like supporting different compression-algorithms like PACKBITS, DEFLATE, LZW, etc) to another (browser-supported) raster-format (so one could feed it as a `data:img`-source).

There is a library called **[Tiffus](http://code.google.com/p/tiffus/)**: a client side pure Javascript imaging library to load, save and manipulate binary images.

The original project aim was was to create a plain Javascript chrome extension which can convert single/multi page TIFF image/s to BMP/GIF image (this is where the name came from).

However now it supports:

- Windows BMP (no compression, RLE)
- OS/2 BMP
- ICO
- GIF
- JPEG
- PNG
- TIFF

and currently supports the folloing image functions:

- load
- save
- resize
- flip
- invert color

Basically it works like this:

1. Source image downloaded as Binary Data using XMLHttpRequest with
   MimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined'); (future: HTML5
   Canvas ImageData)
2. Imageprocessing using Tiffus
3. Desination image shown as Data URI scheme (future: HTML5 Canvas ImageData)

Note that according to the above; the author expects to use HTML5 Canvas `ImageData` in the future.

Hope this helps!