# Javascript TIFF Image Conversion

Tags: javascript, html, image-conversion

I am looking for a way to convert a Tiff image into a png so modern browsers can render it. I have looked at [Tiffus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310801/is-there-an-html5-method-for-displaying-a-tiff-image-data-already-loaded-into-me), but that doesn't look like it is being developed anymore. I have also tried writing a conversion program in C# and sending through [JSIL](http://jsil.org/), but that didn't work either. I have also tried using [Tiff-js](https://github.com/GPHemsley/tiff-js) but the sample project isn't working. Does anyone know how to do this? I know I can do it in C#/server-side but we want to try to do it client side.

Comment: As far as I know, TIFF is just some kind of image-container. There can be lots of compression formats and lots of different color codings inside. I think there are even multi-page TIFFs. Can you specify a concrete TIFF-format?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach We are using 1 bit, CCITT Group 4 FAX

Comment: @CameronTinker We can already do it server-side using System.Drawing.Bitmap. We want to see if there is a client-side way to do it.

Answer (score 16):

I ported LibTIFF to Javascript with Emscripten ( https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js , demo: http://seikichi.github.io/tiff.js/basic.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use [UTIF.js](https://github.com/photopea/UTIF.js/), that can not only decode but also encode in TIFF format.
Supports Black & White, Grayscale, RGB and Paletted images.
Supports Fax 3 and Fax 4 (CCITT), JPEG, LZW, PackBits and other compressions (1,3,4,5,6,7,8,32773,32809)