# How to convert TIFF to JPG or PNG at client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to display TIFF image at HTML page. But Chrome doesn't display TIFF image. How can I convert TIFF to JPG or PNG by javascript? If converting at the client is impossible, could you please tell me how to do it on the nodeJs server? Thank for any help.

Comment: Your title and your tags are at odds with one another. "at client" would presumably mean "in the browser." [tag:node.js] on the other hand, is not in the browser. Pick one. :-)

Comment: The easiest solution is to simply save the TIFF image in a web-friendly format using any TIFF supported image editor.

Comment: Separately: What research have you done? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Generally, when you are looking for js implementation of that file type, just google `(file extension).js`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I updated my question. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript TIFF Image Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979696/javascript-tiff-image-conversion)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My user wants to upload the TIFF image then display it on the HTML page. But Chrome doesn't support to display TIFF image type. So I tried to convert TIFF to png or jpg.

Comment: I don't know any browser supporting TIFF natively. TIFF can be a lot of beasts, so doing it yourself might be hard too.