# Convert tiff to png and display in browser

Tags: javascript, html, tiff

Since tiff cannot show in most browser, I'm thinking about transfer it to png and display the png in html. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript TIFF Image Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979696/javascript-tiff-image-conversion)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this library.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiff-to-png

```
var ConvertTiff = require('tiff-to-png');

var options = {
logLevel: 1
};

var converter = new ConvertTiff(options);

var tiffs = [
  '/home/tiffs/document_one.tif',
  '/home/tiffs/document_two.tif'
];
var location = '/srv/www/mysite/public/documents';

converter.convertArray(tiffs, location);
```

Comment: How to use tiff-to-png npm package in Angular 9?

Comment: This won't work in a browser, only NodeJS.